# Invert background image of parent element with CSS

Tags: css, html

I have kind of a hard problem here (I think). Assume the following HTML:

```
<div id="page">
   <div id="menubar"></div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS defined on it:

```
#page {
   background: url("some-image.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover; 
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}

#menubar {
    background-color: rgb(36, 108, 228);
    background-color: rgba(0, 50, 255, 0.6);
}
```

In words, I have a page div with a fully covering background image and a menubar with a 60% opacity, so the background of div #page shines through the menubar. However, I would like to have the background shining through the menubar AND invert the colors of the background where it shines through the menubar.

I could not find a solution online, since the invert filter can only be applied to entire images as far as I am aware. So therefore, I really hope that someone on SO knows some nice trick to pull this of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If what you're trying is to do is to target an element's parent via CSS, it's impossible.

Comment: One way to do that would be to have a second image of the same dimensions, that is the “inverted” version of your original image, and use that as fixed background image for your navigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically you don't need to "target" the parent's background image.

In CSS you can just `inherit` the properties of the parent into the child element.

```
#page {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/nature/") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Copy the parent's image properties */
#menubar {
    background: inherit;
}
```

Another option would be to just have `#page` and `#menubar` selectors on the same declaration.

```
#page, #menubar {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/nature/") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Either way, once you give the `#menubar` the same background, you can add another rule to invert the colors on the `#menubar`.

```
#menubar {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfu4e4pn/)

*Note: Added invert and background color to the the child element just inside the `#menubar` to revert the colors.*

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer! It works like a charm, which I wouldn't have expected, since I assumed that a background on a smaller div would render differently. Thanks again!

Comment: @rcijvat: this is a special case due to `fixed` background. Without that, this would be much harder to do.